Do current moderators have to nominate themselves to continue to be moderators?
I see that we are up for another moderator election. Do the current moderators have to nominate themselves, or can they be nominated by others, or will the automatically be included in the election?

Per the announcement post (emphasis mine):

Bioacoustics Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for a special election on July 30, 2024 to bring in 2 more moderators

Additionally, Stack Exchange sites will virtually never have less than 3 moderators on the site; consequently if you see an election with 2 spots it's because mods are being added :D
Meaning that they do not need to run; they will continue serving in their current capacity.

Ah ok thank you...I missed that 'more'!
